# how to inherit quick launch bar for entire site collection?

Tags: site-collection, quick-launch

We have created a site collection (root web), it has a quick launch bar.

Then, created a subsite, it has its own quick launch bar.

Is there a way to use the same quick launch bar for the entire site collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the below powershell code. You need to

```
# get a sitecollection object(SPSite)
$SPSite = Get-SPSite -Identity "http://sp2010/"

# loop through all the subwebs(SPWebs) in the site collection
foreach ($SPWeb in $SPSite.AllWebs)
{
   # check so that this is not the root web
  if (!$SPWeb.IsRootWeb)
  {

     # allow unsafe updates
     $SPWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = $true

     # Get a PublishingWeb object for the current web
     $SPPubWeb = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingWeb]::GetPublishingWeb($SPWeb)

     #Current Navigation Settings
     $SPPubWeb.Navigation.InheritGlobal = $true
     $SPPubWeb.Update()

     #RESET unsafe updates

     $SPWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = $false

     Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green $SPWeb.Url.ToString()  " - Done"

     $SPWeb.Dispose()
 }


 $SPSite.Dispose()
```

Comment: will try this one

Answer (score 2):

You can activate **SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure** features on the site collection level. Then Go to the site settings of your subsite and find **Navigation** link in **Look and Feel** section. In **Current Navigation** settings select **Display the same navigation items as the parent site**

Comment: Suppose I have root web -> subsite1 -> subsite2 -> subsite 3. Then is it possible to get navigation bar of root web into the subsite 1,2, and 3? Thanks.

Comment: We have 1 web applicaiton with 500 site colelctions and subsites and more subsites within.. Is there a way to do it in powershell?